Adding a new fulltext column results in degraded performance
I have a search table with a schema something like this:
CREATE TABLE `product_search` (
  `product_id` int NOT NULL,
  `search` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`search`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

It has around 2 million rows with a data size of approx 2.5GB and index size of 300MB. This is working very well.
Recently I needed a slightly different and reduced set of datapoints to search so I tried adding an additional column to provide an alternate fulltext search.
ALTER TABLE `product_search` ADD `alt_search` TEXT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `product_search` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (`alt_search`);

Which results in:
CREATE TABLE `product_search` (
  `product_id` int NOT NULL,
  `search` text NOT NULL,
  `alt_search` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`search`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `alt_search` (`alt_search`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

I then populated the new column with data. This added approx 700MB to the table size.
The result was that running any query against this table now resulted in a brief (1.5 sec) delay. Previously queries were more or less instantaneous. Now no matter what I do with this table it is very slow to respond.  Even running EXPLAIN ... statements on my query has the same delay - which I find very odd.
I ended up moving my new column to an entirely new table and everything is working fine.
Sample query:
SELECT * FROM product_search WHERE MATCH (`alt_search`) AGAINST ('FOOBAR');

My InnoDB settings look something like this:

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 8
innodb_lru_scan_depth          = 512
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 24G
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 128M
innodb_log_file_size           = 1G
innodb_read_io_threads         = 64
innodb_write_io_threads        = 64
innodb_io_capacity             = 5000
innodb_thread_concurrency      = 0
innodb_stats_on_metadata       = 0
innodb_ft_enable_stopword      = 0
innodb_ft_min_token_size       = 2

Can anyone offer an explanation about what would cause this hanging / degraded performance when adding that new column?

Please show us the SELECT.
